# Cannot scroll a ListWheelScrollView inside another Scrollable Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, scrollview

I currently have a `ListWheelScrollView` as part of one of the children of a `ListView`. The `ListWheelScrollView` is horizontal (using a `RotatedBox`) and the `ListView` is vertical, however, I am unable to scroll it unless the `Physics` of the `ListView` is set to `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`. Is it possible to fix this, without having to make my own widget that achieves the same thing as a `ListWheelScrollView`?

Edit:
As per request, here is some sample code that can reproduce the issue:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(height: 300, color: Colors.black),
              Container(height: 300, color: Colors.red),
              Container(height: 300, color: Colors.green),
              Container(
                height: 300,
                child: RotatedBox(
                  quarterTurns: 1,
                  child: ListWheelScrollView(
                    itemExtent: 25,
                    children: const [
                      Text(
                        "something",
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "something",
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "something",
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "something",
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "something",
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "something",
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              Container(height: 300, color: Colors.blue),
              Container(height: 300, color: Colors.orange),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the above sample code, once you reach the `ListWheelScrollView`, you can not scroll on it.

However, if we set the `Physics` of the `SingleChildScrollView` to `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`, like below, then we are able to scroll the `ListWheelScrollView`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(height: 300, color: Colors.black),
              Container(height: 300, color: Colors.red),
              Container(height: 300, color: Colors.green),
              Container(
                height: 300,
                child: RotatedBox(
                  quarterTurns: 1,
                  child: ListWheelScrollView(
                    itemExtent: 25,
                    children: const [
                      Text(
                        "something",
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "something",
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "something",
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "something",
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "something",
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "something",
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              Container(height: 300, color: Colors.blue),
              Container(height: 300, color: Colors.orange),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include sample code that will reproduce the issue

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Apologies for the delay, added the sample code.